# why test coverage includes all classes and triggers when creating an unmanaged package with selected classes?

Tags: package, code-coverage

Trying to create an unmanaged package with few classes but i am getting the following error when i try to "Upload". There are other Apex classes and triggers in my free dev org for which i do not want to create test classes. What is the workaround for this? Do i need to create unit test classes for all the classes which does not participate in the package?

[image]

why test coverage includes all classes and triggers when creating an unmanaged package with selected classes?

Comment: When creating any sort of package in a Dev org, that should be the ONLY purpose for that org.  Test around stuff in one org, but when you want to go create a package, have a dedicated org for it.

Comment: Are you certain this is the case? Maybe you are missing a few applicable test classes from the unmanaged package definition?